# Bash script for removing specific file from certain subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

On a unix server, I'm trying to figure out how to remove a file, say "example.xls", from any subdirectories that start with v0 ("v0*").

I have tried something like:

```
find . -name "v0*" -type d -exec find . -name "example.xls" -type f 
-exec rm {} \;
```

But i get errors. I have a solution but it works too well, i.e. it will delete the file in any subdirectory, regardless of it's name:

```
find . -type f -name "example.xls" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to do it in two steps -- i.e. first find the directories, and then the files -- you can use `xargs` to make it in a single line, like

```
find . -name "v0*" -type d | \
   xargs -l -I[] \
       find [] -name "example.xls" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

what it does, is first generating a list of viable directory name, and let xargs call the second find with the names locating the file name within that directory

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find -path '*/v0*/example.xls' -delete
```

This matches only files named `example.xls` which, somewhere in its path, has a parent directory name that starts with `v0`.

Note that since `find` offers `-delete` as an action, it is not necessary to invoke the external executable `rm`.

#### Example

Consider this directory structure:

```
$ find .
.
./a
./a/example.xls
./a/v0
./a/v0/b
./a/v0/b/example.xls
./a/v0/example.xls
```

We can identify files `example.xls` who have one of their parent directories named `v0*`:

```
$ find -path '*/v0*/example.xls'
./a/v0/b/example.xls
./a/v0/example.xls
```

To delete those files:

```
find -path '*/v0*/example.xls' -delete
```

#### Alternative: find only those files directly under directory `v0*`

```
find -regex '.*/v0[^/]*/example.xls'
```

Using the above directory structure, this approach returns one file:

```
$ find -regex '.*/v0[^/]*/example.xls'
./a/v0/example.xls
```

To delete such files:

```
find -regex '.*/v0[^/]*/example.xls' -delete
```

#### Compatibility

Although my tests were performed with GNU `find`, both `-regex` and `-path` are required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and also supported by [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).